# Check similarity between elements in tuple Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, similarity

I have the following list:

```
list= [(12.947999999999979,5804),(100000.0,1516),(12.948000000000008,844),(12.948000000000036,172),(18.252000000000066,92)]
```

The first element in the tuple represents the value whereas the second element of the tuple represents the frequency that this value appears in a document. My question is how can I cluster the similar elements of the list (such as the 1st element and the 3rd element of the list) and combine their frequencies?

Comment: set up a threshold within which two values are considered to belong in the same cluster and combine their frequencies.

Comment: What do you consider "similar"? Specify the p`recission. For example, numbers with less than 10^-6 difference should be grouped.

Comment: thank you for the response. can you also provide an example code

Comment: @Adirio basically the values that start with 12.9 to be grouped together as one value

Comment: @LoniF Iterate through your list and for every element you either create a new cluster or combine it with an existing. so `for... if: else:`. you can do this Loni! it does get a bit tricky if you have values such as `[(12.9,5804),(12.8,1516),(12.7,844)]` as the last will not be included with a thres of 0.1 if the cluster is defined based on the first element.

Comment: LoniF do you know what `Counter` type is?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thanks for the answer. I will try it :)

Comment: @Adirio yes I know but not a clear idea on how to use it

Comment: Look at my answer, it gives you an example, also look for `Counter.most_common()` method as it will probably be useful to order your output by the frequency.

Comment: @Adirio indeed I used most_common() to create the list but then had to add the similar values and their frequencies. your answer does exactly what I expected

Comment: If you had it as a counter you could avoid one step, will edit my answer.

Comment: If you do it with `Counter.items()` instead of `Counter.most_common()` you avoid ordering the result as it is not needed and it takes time (ordering may be quite time expensive). Is the comment about `data` clear enough?

Comment: @Adirio it is perfect. Thank you very much, it was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Counter` element and `round()` to the number of decimals you want. By the way do NOT use the reserved word `list`:

```
from collections import Counter

l= [(12.947999999999979,5804),(100000.0,1516),(12.948000000000008,844),(12.948000000000036,172),(18.252000000000066,92)]
precision = 3

c = Counter()

for value, times in l:
    c.update([round(value, precision)]*times)
```

If you already have the data in a counter you could do this directly:

```
from collections import Counter

# data = Counter()  # This is the counter where you have the data
precision = 3

joined = Counter()

for value, times in data.items():
    joined.update([round(value, precision)]*times)

data = joined
```